# Conjecture on relationship between sum of primes and powers of 2

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $x$ and $y$ be any odd $\mathbb{N}\geq 2$, and
$n = 2^a$ where $a$ is any $\mathbb{N} \geq 1$:
$$
{x+y \over n} = n^2, n < x < y
$$

when true, then $x$ and $y \in \mathbb{P}$ .

---

Anyone see any flaw(s) in this, or any obvious explanation which I (most possibly) have overlooked in the heat of the moment?

Is anything known about this; if so, is there an explanation on why this conjecture is true/false?

Edit 1:

Fixed some **obvious** flaws.

Edit 2:

Fixed conditions.

Comment: I think you meant $x$ and $y\in\Bbb{P}$ or in a more compact form: $(x,y)\in\Bbb{P}^2$ ;)

Comment: $\frac{4 + 4}{2} = 2^2.$

Comment: Thanks for the corrections.

Comment: If you rearrange your expression, you get $x+y = n^3$. I think your statement is missing something important (or you have the implication the wrong way) because you could pick $x=1$ and $y=n^3-1$ and the equality would hold, but $x$ would not be prime.

Comment: Fixed some flaws, please re-check if you care to do so! :)

Comment: One bumps into counterexamples too quickly, $3+213=216$, many others with $216$, like $121$ and $95$.

Comment: @André Nicolas:
What $n$ for ${3+213 \over n} = n^2$ ?

Comment: Doesn't this conjecture contradict Goldbach conjecture?

Comment: @JohnWO Take the cube root of $3+213$ and see for yourself.

Comment: @JohnWO $216=6^3$.

Comment: $x=1, y=n^3-1$ is always a counter example to your new conjecture... More generarily, if $k<n^3$ is any composite number, $x=k$ and $y=n^3-k$ is a counterexample...

Comment: Not any longer, I should think.

Comment: @JohnWO: For most recent version, $64=49+15$.

Comment: @JohnWO Pick $n$ arbitrary, $x=n^2-1$ or $n^2$ depending on the parity of $n$ and $y=n^3-x$. $x$ is always composite...

Comment: It's back to the drawing-board I guess! :)

Comment: @JohnWO Keep in mind that among any three consecutive integers one is always composite...So whatever you try to "draw", the restrictions on $x$ and $y$ must force them not be able to take three consecutive integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ and $Y$ be subsets of the naturals. For any given $y\in Y$, the number of pairs $a,b\in X$ such that $a+b=y$ is at most equal to the number of $a\in X$ such that $a\le y$. Thus the number of pairs of primes adding to $m$ grows asymptotically no more than $\frac{\log m}{m}$ by the prime number theorem; at any rate all we need to accept is that primes grow sublinearly, i.e. $o(m)$.

The number of ordered pairs of positive odd numbers that add up to an even number $m$ may be computed exactly as $\frac{m}{2}$, which grows linearly in the value $m$. Whether or not $m$ is restricted to perfect cubes or other special sets is of no meaningful significance. Similarly, if we impose further modular-arithmetic conditions on $a,b$ besides being odd numbers, and force them to always be distinct, and view the pairs as unordered, their count will still grow linearly with $m$ all the same.

It is at face value impossible for a linearly growing collection to fit snugly inside another collection (prime pairs) that grows sublinearly. This is the conceptual explanation of why one would immediately expect a conjecture of this form to be false simply on statistical grounds.

Answer (score 1):

How about $x=12,y=15,n=3?$

For the update, $x=27,y=189,n=6$

Comment: If you don't mind, please check again, as I left out some key elements in my original and 1st edit.

Comment: There really is nothing to make $x,y$ prime. $x=25,y=39,n=4$

Answer (score 0):

$\dfrac{x+y}{n}=n^2 \implies x+y=2^{\alpha+2 \alpha}$

$x+y =2^{3 \alpha} \implies x+y=8^ {\alpha}$

To have $y>x>n$, you need to have $\alpha \ge 2$

I see $x,y \not \in$ prime number set.For instance when $\alpha=2$, $(x,y)=(49,15).(9,55)$ you get only few solutions for $\alpha=2$ because the density of primes to number of possible odds is very high in the close.

What happens when $\alpha >2$? You get more solutions than $\alpha=2$.